# What is Error: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList is not a valid

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j

EDIT:  Still no fix, but I know what value being returned from the cypher is causing the error:

[43.4171031, 37.5049815, 43.4171031, 37.5049815]

it is coming from a bbox as a spatial query:

```
val query = "call blah blah yield node return node.fromDate as fromDate, node.bbox as bbox  ORDER BY node.toDateFormatLong DESC";
```

It does NOT like that return node.bbox as bbox, I have to take that out for the query to work.

if I do I get the data frame back.  If I don't I get the error:

```
defined class DateLayerData
defined class ChangeScoreObj
changeScoreMap: java.util.Map[Integer,ChangeScoreObj] = {}
doCalculation: (lat1: BigDecimal, lon1: BigDecimal, lat2: BigDecimal, lon2: BigDecimal, radius: Double)Unit
main: (args: Array[String])Unit
MinLat: 34.6 minlon 40.9 maxlat: 34.7 maxlon: 41
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1370)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1367)
  at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j.loadDataFrame(Neo4j.scala:280)
  at doCalculation(<console>:114)
  at main(<console>:89)
  ... 81 elided
```

So guessing I am using Option wrong?

```
val initialDf2 = neo.cypher(query).loadDataFrame  //this seems to fail on empty collection
initialDf2.take(1).headOption.map(_.getString(1)).foreach(println)
```

This line above is ran inside a loop.   Part of a doCalculation function which is called over and over again with different values etc.

Trying to load a data frame that once back from NEO4j looks like this inside NEO4j:

```
-1  “Detected”  1   20161104    3318    37.5049815  43.4171031  20161023     “filename.val” 9.2 "23OCT16"   [43.4171031, 37.5049815, 43.4171031, 37.5049815]
```

So I make the query call to get one of many rows that looks like the above one:

```
try {
 val initialDf2 = neo.cypher(query).loadDataFrame
 val someVal = initialDf2.collectAsList()
 val detectt = someVal.get(0).getString(1) //try to get the second field
 println(detectt)
} catch {
   case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace
}
```

I do have a try catch because sometimes the query sent to the cypher returns nothing (I have no idea how else to handle that)

```
  17/09/18 08:44:48 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 298.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 298.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 298.0 (TID 298, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList is not a valid external type for schema of string
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, altitude), DoubleType) AS altitude#1678
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, detect_type), StringType), true) AS detect_type#1679
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 2, gtype), LongType) AS gtype#1680L
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 3, toDateFormatLong), LongType) AS toDateFormatLong#1681L
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 4, change_area), LongType) AS change_area#1682L
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 5, latitude), DoubleType) AS latitude#1683
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 6, longitude), DoubleType) AS longitude#1684
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 7, fromDateFormatLong), LongType) AS fromDateFormatLong#1685L
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 8, iids), StringType), true) AS iids#1686
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 9, detect_strength), DoubleType) AS detect_strength#1687
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 10, fromDate), StringType), true) AS fromDate#1688
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 11, bbox), StringType), true) AS bbox#1689
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkSession.scala:573)
```

Comment: Don't know about the error, but some Scala/Spark advice: First, instead of calling `collectAsList` and then `get(0)`, you can use `DataFrame.first()` which would be much (much) faster for larger dataframes, and safer. As for the try-catch, a good way to handle possibly null values is using `Option`, so altogether: `Option(initialDf2.first()).map(_.getString(1)).foreach(println)` would print the result you want (or nothing if empty).

Comment: Thanks so much, let me try this.  Scala/Spark advice I need a ton of, I am trying to parallelize code I didn't write the best I can and never done this before so it has been like pulling teeth.

Comment: Complained about the println for some reason?  edited answer.

Comment: oh, sorry - my bad! `first()` throws this exception for empty DataFrames, use `initialDf2.take(1).headOption.map(_.getString(1)).foreach(println)`

Comment: okay trying this, is that all wrapped in Option() still?

Comment: no need, `headOption` already returns an `Option`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154711/discussion-between-codejoy-and-tzach-zohar).